# Response in a Strange format: Ljava.lang.Object;@43da8f90

Tags: java, android, parsing

I'm calling a service that returns this string response:

```
{id_richiesta=d877467614e1a80a1bade73d7014c595, risposta={percorsi=[Ljava.lang.Object;@43da8f90, abilitata=1, id_news=-1, monitorata=1}}
```

It's a very strange format.
How can I parse this? Above all `Ljava.lang.Object;@43da8f90;` this is an array of this element:

1. string **id_percorso**
2. string **descrizione**
3. string **capolinea**

Answer (score 2):

> percorsi=[Ljava.lang.Object;@43da8f90

This happens because the `Object` you are using doesn't have a `toString()` method on it. Or if it does, it is using the default implementation provided by `java.lang.Object`. In order to get around this, put your data in your own kind of object and override `toString()` to print it out how you want.

Comment: I don't know how can I get the pair key/value? By stringtokenizer? Some example please –  Marco Ciampini

Answer (score 0):

what is `Ljava.lang.Object;@43da8f90`?

It is class name follow by at sign and hash code at the end, hash code of the object.All classes in Java inherit from the Object class, directly or indirectly . The Object class has some basic methods like clone(), toString(), equals(),.. etc.  The default `toString()` method in Object prints `“class name @ hash code”.`

What is the **solution**?

You need to override `toString` method  in your class because it is going to give you clear information about the object in readable format that you can understand.

The merit about overriding `toString`:

> Help the programmer for **logging** and **debugging of Java program**
>
> Since **toString** is defined in **java.lang.Object** and does not give valuable information, so it is
>      good practice to override it for subclasses.